# Predict on test data using Scikit-learn's pipelines and GridSearchCV with custom transformers

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to combine GridSearchCV with a Pipeline. The code looks like this:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing', preprocess), 
                       ('feature_selection', feature_selector), 
                       ('sampling', sampler), 
                       ('model', RandomForestClassifier())])
search = GridSearchCV(pipe, hparam_grid[model_name], 
                      cv=cross_validator, 
                      n_jobs=-1, scoring=scoring, refit='balanced_accuracy')
```

Here `preprocess` is a custom transformer (from `TransformerMixin`), that has `fit` and a `transform` methods. You can think of it has a custom `StandardScaler` method.

The all thing seems to be working properly. But now I'm facing some issues when I want to apply the fitted pipeline to my test dataset. If I call `search.predict(X_test)`, it does not work because the number of features are different (the `feature_selection` step might drop some columns). I cannot simply call `search.transform(X_test)` because `RandomForestClassifier` does not have such method.

Is there a way to apply the fitted pipeline to the test data without doing it step by step (e.g., `X_test_processed = search.best_estimator_[0].transform(X_test)`, ...)? Is adding a `predict` method to my custom transformers a possibility?

Comment: I think you have some problem with `feature_selection` because when you call `predict(X_test)`, `pipeline` will only call `.transform` for all steps except the last one.

Comment: Provide some example for reproducible error, we might be able to help better!